# Odd bugs when image processing with Pillow (in tkinter)

Tags: python, jpeg, gif, python-imaging-library

I'm having a weird problem when trying to use [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) to display images in tkinter.
I tried originally displaying images in the default tkinter way, which worked fine for gifs:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
src = tk.PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\Matt\\Desktop\\K8pnR.gif")

label = tk.Label(root, image = src)
label.pack()
```

([K8pnR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1G0W.gif) is just a random gif I found on imgur)
This works great but the only problem is I want to display other file types. This lead me to Pillow, as I am working in Python 3.4. I tried to start with displaying the same file, but using Pillow:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image
root = tk.Tk()

src = Image.open("C:\\Users\\Matt\\Desktop\\K8pnR.gif")
img = tk.PhotoImage(file = src)

label = tk.Label(image = img, master = root)
label.pack()
```

This leads to a very weird and ugly **no such file or directory** error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\pil test.py", line 7, in <module>
  img = tk.PhotoImage(file = src)
File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3416, in __init__
  Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3372, in __init__
  self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "<PIL.GifImagePlugin.GifImageFile image   mode=P size=494x260 at 0x26A6CD0>": no such file or directory
```

I tried different files, different filetypes, and even reinstalling Pillow, but I still get the error.
Does anyone know what's going on here? Did I miss something totally obvious?

**Edit:**
When I try the [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32512737/3938489) fix, I get this spooky error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\pil test.py", line 6, in <module>
  img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = src)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 84, in __init__
  image = Image.open(kw["file"])
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2297, in open
  prefix = fp.read(16)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 632, in __getattr__
  raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: read
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lies in this line:

```
img = tk.PhotoImage(file = src)
```

You are using stock `PhotoImage` from tkinter. It is not compatible with `PIL` you want to use `ImageTk` from `PIL`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
root = tk.Tk()

src = Image.open("C:\\Users\\Matt\\Desktop\\K8pnR.gif")
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = src)

label = tk.Label(image = img, master = root)
label.pack()
```

Here is documentation of stock `PhotoImage` class: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm , it accepts only path in constructor.

Comment: I am getting another weird error... please check my edit.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it seems that the problem is `file = src`. Don't name that param or name it correctly, that is `image = src`.

Comment: Ahhh... Thank you! I knew it was probably a small thing I missed... I was ripping my hair out. You are awesome!